# Nuevos ID Post con numeros demasiados altos en Woocommerce (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Escribo porque tengo un problema con mi Woocommerce, estoy migrando de un sitio a otros ocupando las herramientas nativas de WC, al importar los productos no tengo los mismos id de post, muy por el contrario, obtengo unos id muy altos en relacion al contenido de la nueva web, ejemplo: un id de mi sitio anterior es 251095 y en nuevo sitio es 3270000, siendo que basicamente ambas web tienen el mismo contenido.

Agradezco cualquiera ayuda para dejar los valores o al menos con una diferencia no tan amplia.

Saludos!

Comment: Hola! Puedo saber en que te afecta la diferencia de ID? Si no te tienes un desarrollo personalizado en el que utilizaras los ID anteriores, no veo en que pueda afectarte.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estamos migrando de un sistema antiguo a uno nuevo que funciona también como Marketplace, entonces necesitamos que la información historica anterior al Marketplace quedé intacta, la nueva ya no es relevante que tenga ID con cifras más altas.